# How to detect if an iOS or an Android user is "present"?

Tags: android, ios, messaging, instant, user-presence

We are developing an instant messaging App, and would need to display the "*presence*" of user's friends with a green dot on their avatars.

"*Presence*" goes far beyond "my_app_is_opened_and_on_focus", it means (and I guess one could have many definitions of "presence"): user has been using his device to do anything (even just checking time) during the last 2 or 5 minutes.

Any idea on how could we get this "*presence*" or "*generic recent activity*" information and log it on our server even if our app is closed? (on iOS and Android)

Comment: I would consider using "is the screen on?" as a proxy for "is the user present?".

Comment: As far as i know, you cannot detect activity outside your app on iOS.

Comment: For Android in the onCreate for the activity just tell the server the user has open the app and when they leave send one saying they left.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a service running in the background to check the screen status.

For Android: Use `BroadcastReceiver` for these actions.

```
android.intent.action.SCREEN_OFF
android.intent.action.SCREEN_ON
```

when receiving `SCREEN_ON` or `SCREEN_OFF` send a small message to the server to track the activity of the user.